# "Bad Route" error when trying to test addBooking function using Postman in an Express.js API

Tags: typescript, express, routes, postman, web-api-testing

I'm building an API using Express.js, and I have created a function called addBooking to add a new booking to the database. The function expects several specific fields in the request body, such as start, end, userId, etc. Here is the addBooking function:

```
export async function addBooking(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    const {
      start,
      end,
      userId,
      parkingBayId,
      parkingMapId,
      companyId,
      buildingId,
    } = req.body;

    if (
      !start ||
      !end ||
      !userId ||
      !parkingBayId ||
      !parkingMapId ||
      !companyId ||
      !buildingId
    ) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Missing required fields" });
    }

    const newBooking = await BookingModel.create({
      start,
      end,
      userId,
      parkingBayId,
      parkingMapId,
      companyId,
      buildingId,
    });

    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Booking created successfully",
      id: newBooking.id,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const errors = ("" + error).split("\n");
    res.status(400).json({ message: errors });
  }
}
```

When I try to test this function using Postman, I keep getting a "Bad Route" error.
Here is the router for my bookings:

```
import express from "express";
import {
  addBooking,
  editBookingById,
  getBookingById,
} from "../database/controllers/booking.controller";

export const bookingRouter = express.Router();

bookingRouter.use(express.json());

// Add a booking
bookingRouter.post("/add", addBooking);

// Get a booking by its Id
bookingRouter.get("/bookings/:id", getBookingById);

// Edit a booking by id
bookingRouter.put("/:id", editBookingById);
```

Here is the index.ts file that serves as the entry point to my application:

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import { userRouter } from "./routes/users";
import { buildingRouter } from "./routes/buildings";
import { parkingMapsRouter } from "./routes/parkingMaps";
import { bookingRouter } from "./routes/bookings";
import { companyRouter } from "./routes/companies";
import { config } from "./config";

const port = config.port;
const app: Express = express();

// Use middleware and routers
app.use("/users", userRouter);
app.use("/buildings", buildingRouter);
app.use("/parkingMaps", parkingMapsRouter);
app.use("/bookings", bookingRouter);
app.use("/companies", companyRouter);
app.use("/public", express.static("public"));

// Catch-all for requests to non-existent routes
app.all("*", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(404).json({ message: "Bad route" });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`[SERVER]: Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

When I try to test this function using Postman, I keep getting a "Bad Route" error that has to do with the catch-all in my index.ts file. In postman I get at Status: 404 not found.

Steps to Reproduce:
Set the HTTP method to POST in Postman.
Enter the endpoint URL where the addBooking function is hosted.
Under Headers, set Content-Type to application/json.
In the Body tab, I select raw and input the following JSON:

```
{
  "start": "2023-09-19T10:00:00.000Z",
  "end": "2023-09-19T12:00:00.000Z",
  "userId": 1,
  "parkingBayId": 5,
  "parkingMapId": 2,
  "companyId": 3,
  "buildingId": 4
}
```

When using this in my body of my request, I am supposed to get the response "Booking created successfully".